# Is there any way to get current caption's text from video tag using Video.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video, video.js

I want to get current subtitles' text during playing a video (and than implement own subtitles block (i.e. to hide original) and also use the information in a few different ways). Currently I use [videojs](https://github.com/videojs/video.js) for my player. Is there any way to get current caption's string from it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VideoJs TextTracks Cues empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23067294/videojs-texttracks-cues-empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
    videojs("example_video_1").ready(function() {
        myvideo = this;

        var aTextTrack =  this.textTracks()[0];
        aTextTrack.on('loaded', function() {
            console.log('here it is');
            cues = aTextTrack.cues();   //subtitles content is here
            console.log('Ready State', aTextTrack.readyState()) 
            console.log('Cues', cues);
        });

        //this method call triggers the subtitles to be loaded and loaded trigger
        aTextTrack.show();
    });
```

---

Result:

[image: Result]

---

PS. Code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23092699/3084258).

Answer (score 4):

This code gets the current cue and put into the `<span>` element

```
(function(){

    var video = document.querySelector('video');
    var span = document.querySelector('span');

    if (!video.textTracks) return;

    var track = video.textTracks[0];
    track.mode = 'hidden';

    track.oncuechange = function(e) {

        var cue = this.activeCues[0];
        if (cue) {
            span.innerHTML = '';
            span.appendChild(cue.getCueAsHTML());
        }

    };
})()
```

Here is the tutorial :[Getting Started With the Track Element](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/track/basics/?redirect_from_locale=ko)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can add a **cuechange** event listener when your video loads. This can get you the current track's caption text. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/video-captions-3ocub) is my working example using videojs.

Comment: is there a way to make it on pure JS?

Answer (score 0):

```
var videoElement = document.querySelector("video");
var textTracks = videoElement.textTracks; 
var textTrack = textTracks[0]; 
var kind = textTrack.kind // e.g. "subtitles"
var mode = textTrack.mode
```

Try this one

Comment: you're on the good way, but to get the text content you have to go until the `textTrack.cues`which will give all vtt cues, and then get their `text` property.

Comment: Also, video.js does provide a custom fallback for firefox (don't know why btw), which won't fill the textTracks property of the video

Answer (score 0):

Use the HTML5 Video API to get the current source, the split the src using `/` and `.` to get the name.

[Media API](http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html)

The above link has all the available API in the HTML5 video player. Your plugin uses HTML5 video player!

Comment: hmm does this really answers the question?