# How to get active subtitles text from video using pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, video, video-subtitles

Looking for a solution which is written in pure JS. It will be used as an integration into a web page.

*P.S. Another reference.* Here is some example for Video.js
[Is there any way to get current caption's text from video tag using Video.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32043406/is-there-any-way-to-get-current-captions-text-from-video-tag)

...but I still need it in pure JS.

Also, used this example:

```
(function(){

    var video = document.querySelector('video');
    var span = document.querySelector('span');

    if (!video.textTracks) return;

    var track = video.textTracks[0];
    track.mode = 'hidden';

    track.oncuechange = function(e) {

        var cue = this.activeCues[0];
        if (cue) {
            span.innerHTML = '';
            span.appendChild(cue.getCueAsHTML());
        }

    };
})()
```

...but "track.oncuechange" never happened.

Comment: Please provide us some code so that we can better understand what you would like to achieve.

Comment: @SparkFountain, the question in the title. What's unclear for you?

Comment: @Kirby did you ever find how to accomplish this?

Comment: @ManuelAbascal, no, haven't dig it too deep.